# how to dissect a equilateral triangle into a square with a sheet of paper

Tags: geometry

given an equilateral triangle $ABC$ how to dissect it so we can rearrange it into a square . we can cut it into a rectangle and then we can find the side length of the square with $GM$ theorem. is there 
any other ways

Comment: A quick Google search found [this](https://www.cutoutfoldup.com/109-turn-an-equilateral-triangle-into-a-square.php)

Comment: This is Dudeney's Haberdasher's problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163167/dudeney-s-solutions-to-haberdashers-problem-exact-measures-of-sections/3163845#3163845